# Wired issue with Internet explorar, Please check the screen

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer

Now today I came across a bug which I am not even sure, is a frontend bug or Backend bug. The thing is My website is working fine in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox but in Internet Explorar it's changing the HTML. Check the image below

[image: HTML has been converterd into wired symbols]

Now Where should i start the debugging process ?

I know it's frontend issue as IE :( can't take much but somybody please help me out with this.

Thank You

**EDIT**

This is how it's looking in the Firefox and Chrome

[image: Chrome and Firefox View]

Comment: Maybe Chrome and FF support the encoding you're using, but IE doesn't

Comment: the encoding is UTF-8, So I suppose it's supported by IE

Comment: Do you declare the encoding in the `<head>`? Does your server return the correct content-type?

Comment: Yes it's declared, I have updated, how it's looking in other browsers

Comment: Why does it say .... Charset uft8 **==$0**? What happens if you remove that? It's not supposed to be there and could make the head crash.

Comment: Because when you click any html tag in chrome console, the $0 means you are referring to that particular element and you can access it in console. it's a Google chrome feature

Comment: Ok. Didn't know that. Is the code generated by php or why is this PHP related?

Comment: Yes the backend  programming language is PHP, so I just mentioned it

Comment: So... Is this part generated by php or not? The head and general html layout

Comment: php is just echoing the head thing, something like laravel blade but it's custom templating.

Comment: I voted close because this question because we can't reproduce the problem. The problem can be found by debugging the html. Something we can't since we don't have the code that produces the problem. You need to debug this yourself. Delete one line at the time from the html and see when the page looks correct

Comment: Please post a sample code or detailed steps for reproducing the issue as only description and images will not help to find the cause of the issue. If you post the code than we can try to test the issue on our side to check the result.